# Не работает плагин на хостинге

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Ребята, подскажите, где ошибка.
Запускаю один и тот же плагин на локальном сервере и на хостинге. На локальном ставится, не выдает ошибок, на хостинге выдает следующее:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
> end of file in
> /srv/www/dev_mirprirody_kz/releases/20150115181259/wp-content/plugins/wayne-audio-player/wayne-song-post-type.php on line 276

А вот сам код:

```
    <?php

function create_wayne_playlist_taxonomies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Wayne Playlists', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Wayne Playlist', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Wayne Playlists' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Wayne Playlists' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Wayne Playlist' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Wayne Playlist' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Wayne Playlist' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Wayne Playlist Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate playlists with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove playlists' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used playlists' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No playlists found.' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Wayne Playlists' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( "wayne_playlist", "wayne_song", array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels, /* NOTICE: Here is where the $labels variable is used */
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false
    ));

}

// hook into the init action and call create_playlist_taxonomies() when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_wayne_playlist_taxonomies', 0 );

// Add song custom post type

function wayne_song_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Wayne Songs', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Song', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Wayne Song', 'wayne_song'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Wayne Song'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Wayne Song'),
        'new_item' => __('New Wayne Song'),
        'view_item' => __('View Song'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Songs'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => null,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', /*'editor', */'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array("wayne_playlist")
      );

    register_post_type( 'wayne_song' , $args );
    /* this ads your post categories to your custom post type */
    //register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'slide');
}

add_action('init', 'wayne_song_register');

// Add new song inputs
function wayne_song_info() {
    global $post;
    $wayne_song_data = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#categorydiv h3 span").text("Add this song to a playlists:");
            jQuery("#category-tabs li:first a").text("All playlists");
            jQuery("#category-tabs li:eq(1)").hide();
            jQuery("#category-adder").hide();
            jQuery("#minor-publishing").hide();
            jQuery("#postbox-container-1 .hndle:first > span").html("Save Song");
            jQuery("#publish").attr("value", "Save Song");

        });
    </script>
    <style>
    #wayne_song_info label{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #464646;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', 'Bitstream Charter', Times, serif;
        text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0;
    }

     #wayne_song_info input{
        font-size: 16px;

    }
    </style>
    <label>Artist</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="wayne_song_artist" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $wayne_song_data['wayne_song_artist'][0]; ?>" /><br><br>

    <label>
        Song File
    </label>
    <div><em> Manually entering a URL will override the song selected in the dropdown. Audio files should be in MP3 format.</em></div>
    <br />
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $songs_query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_mime_type = 'audio/mpeg'", NULL);
    $all_songs = $wpdb->get_results($songs_query);
    ?>
    <select  name="wayne_song_file" style="width: 40%;">
        <?php
        foreach ($all_songs as $song)
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $song->guid; ?>" <?php if ($wayne_song_data['wayne_song_file'][0] == $song->guid) echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $song->post_title; ?></option>
        <?  
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    &nbsp; or &nbsp; 
    <input style="width: 40%;" type="text" name="other_wayne_song_file" placeholder="Enter custom URL" value="<?php echo $wayne_song_data['other_wayne_song_file'][0]; ?>"/>
    <br><br>
    <?php

}

// Add custom columns to song post type
function my_edit_wayne_song_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns = array(

        'title' => __( 'Title' ),
        'image' => __( 'Song Artwork' ),
        'playlists' => __( 'Playlists' )

    );

    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-wayne_song_columns', 'my_edit_wayne_song_columns' ) ;

// Add content to columns to song post type
function my_manage_wayne_song_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;

    switch( $column ) {
        /* If displaying the Title column. */
        case 'title' :

            /* Get the thumbnail. */
            $this_title =  the_title();
            /* If no title is found, output a default message. */
            if ( empty( $this_title ) )
                echo __( 'Unknown' );

            else
                printf( __( '%s ' ), $this_title );

            break;
        /* If displaying the image column. */
        case 'image' :

            /* Get the thumbnail. */
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            /* If no image is found, output a default message. */
            if ( empty( $thumbnail ) )
                echo __( 'Unknown' );

            else
                printf( __( '%s ' ), '<img width="75" src="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" alt=""/>' );

            break;

        /* If displaying the playlists column. */
        case 'playlists' :

            /* Get the playlists. */
            foreach((get_the_terms( $post_id, 'wayne_playlist' )) as $category) { 
                $playlists .=  $category->name . ', '; 
            } 
            $playlists = rtrim($playlists, ', ');
            /* If no playlists are found, output a default message. */
            if ( !$playlists )
                echo __( 'None' );

            else
                printf( __( '%s ' ), $playlists );

            break;

        /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
        default :
            break;
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_wayne_song_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_wayne_song_columns', 10, 2 );

// Customize the featured image labels for each custom post type
function swap_featured_image_metabox_wayne_song($translation, $text, $domain) {
    global $post;
    $translations = get_translations_for_domain( $domain);
    switch( $post->post_type ){

        case 'wayne_song':
            if ( $text == 'Featured Image')
                return $translations->translate( 'Song Artwork' );
            /*if ( $text == 'Categories')
                return $translations->translate( 'Performing in: ' ); */
            if ( $text == 'Remove featured image')
                return $translations->translate( 'Remove Song Artwork' );

            break;
    }
    if ( $text == 'Set featured image')
        return $translations->translate( 'Select an image' );

    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'swap_featured_image_metabox_wayne_song', 10, 4);

// Add custom meta boxes to custom post types
function add_meta_boxes_wayne_song(){

   add_meta_box("wayne_song_info", "Wayne Song Settings", "wayne_song_info", "wayne_song", "normal", "core");
}

add_action("admin_init", "add_meta_boxes_wayne_song");

// Save custom post fields
function save_details_wayne_song(){
  global $post;
  $postID = $post->ID;

  // To prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing...
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
  return $postID;

    // Save Song data
    update_post_meta($postID, "wayne_song_file", $_POST["wayne_song_file"]);
    update_post_meta($postID, "wayne_song_artist", $_POST["wayne_song_artist"]);
    update_post_meta($postID, "other_wayne_song_artist", $_POST["other_wayne_song_artist"]);
    update_post_meta($postID, "other_wayne_song_file", $_POST["other_wayne_song_file"]);

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details_wayne_song');
```

Comment: Извини, конечно, я весь код выделил и вставил к себе, но 276 строки там нет, да и код, видно, что неполный.


Comment: код полный, просто здесь удалились некоторые пустые строки и он скоратился. 276 строка- это самая последняя строка...

Answer (score 1):

[[@harley](/users/18753/harley)](/users/18753/harley), попробуй переустановить плагин на сервере, может, поможет.

Comment: не помогает, на локальном все как надо работает...

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке говорится, что файл окончен внезапно. Возьмите файл wayne-song-post-type.php с локального и перенесите его на сервер!

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach ($all_songs as $song)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $song->guid; ?>" <?php if ($wayne_song_data['wayne_song_file'][0] == $song->guid) echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $song->post_title; ?></option>
    <? <<<< на <?php 
    }
    ?>
```